# What is the best practice of catching exception in this case

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I work on Windows Forms Desktop application that consist of Models that represent objects get it's data from web service, Business layer and UI layer.

I just finished the application and now i try to unit testing it and handle all exception by try and catch errors in business layer like that:

```
    public List<QlmResult> ReleaseBulkKeys(List<string> externalUserIdReleaseList, string activationKey)
    {
        try
        {
            List<QlmResult> qlmResultList = new List<QlmResult>();
            string response = string.Empty;
            foreach (string externalId in externalUserIdReleaseList)
            {
                licenseAuthntication.ReleaseLicense(licenseAuthntication.DefaultWebServiceUrl, activationKey, externalId, out response);
                qlmResultList.Add(new QlmResult { ComputerKey = externalId, Result = response });
            }
            return qlmResultList;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string errorMsg = LoggingManager.CreateExceptionString(ex);
            LoggingManager.SaveExceptionToLogFile(errorMsg);
            throw; // To send Exception to UI Layer;
        }
    }
```

Now i catch the exception in the Business layer and log it to a log.txt file, but i also want to show a message with exception to the user in UI like

```
MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
```

so i used throw; in BL catch {} block and i put another try {} catch {} to the UI Method like that:

```
    private void btnBulkRelease_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (currentProduct != null && currentCustomer != null)
            {
                QlmLicenseManager qlm = new QlmLicenseManager(currentProduct, currentCustomer, configKeys);
                List<QlmResult> bulkResult = qlm.ReleaseBulkKeys(externalIdsLstRelease, txtReleaseActivationKey.Text);

                foreach (var result in bulkResult)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(result.Result);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You Should Select Customer and Product from Settings.");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

My Question: Is it the best practice to show exception in UI and also log it in BL but i using two try {} catch blocks one in BL and other in UI?

Also should i used try {} catch {} in UI or it's recommended to use it in the Business logic methods only?

I think about another two solutions

1- Create an event that will fire to UI when there are an exception in BL.

2- Create a class that contains two properties bool exceptionDetector and string savedException, i will save the BL Exception in the savedException variable and send it to UI to show it when the exceptionDetector changed from false to true.

Is it a good solution?

Comment: Solution 2- is the most appropriate, but create the Exception class in the UI, after storing the exception terminate the BL process, and test the Exception class in UI at BL completion.

Comment: This is not the good way.  If you're coding try..catch Exception on every method,  you're doing it wrong. Catch exeptions in bll only to wrap them or add contextual info. Use an exception handling policy to actually deal with the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to throw it to the UI layer then at least use a custom Exception.

Right now in net you are swallowing a general exception
That is not considered a good practice

Another problem with throw an exception is you are not returning the rows that worked and that can be helpful.

Another options is to return a bool success or status enumeration as an arguement
 [out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx)

I like returning a status enumeration for messages like invalid input

Answer (score 1):

Normally i like to catch all exceptions on my application on a single function.
This way, you are protecting all the code, including asynchronous calls...

```
Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(MyCommonExceptionHandlingMethod)

private static void MyCommonExceptionHandlingMethod(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs t)
{
    //Exception handling...
}
```

*Note: Add the `Application.ThreadException` before `Application.Run()`*

Answer (score 1):

Processing and propagating exceptions is very expensive and I personally do not consider it a best practice to use exceptions to inform the user about violations of business rules.

In my mind, exceptions should be reserved solely for unanticipated problems that the application encounters and should be logged in detail (stack trace, etc) to the event log and/or a file. The information provided in an actual exception exception is generally useless to an end user, so they should likely be masked (i.e. "an unexpected error has occurred, please report this to your system administrator").

For providing the information on business rule violations and exception occurrences between the business layer and the client layers, we use an instance of an error class (error code plus message) as a ref parameter in every business layer method. This implementation allows us to easily provide language-specific error messages to the end users within the client layer without having to bother the business layer with information about the culture the client is currently operating in.